# Direction Fields of Pendulum are different?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, vector-fields

I sought for a way to plot pendulum direction fields and found this superb [post:](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384482/vector-field-of-a-simple-pendulum)

It's been said that this direction field of the Differential equation: $\ddot{\varphi} = \frac{g}{R}\,\sin(\varphi)$ can be interpreted 2 ways:

one via $V = [\omega,-\frac{g}{R}\,\sin(\varphi)]$ $\quad$ ($\dot{\varphi} = \omega$)

the other by $\dfrac{\mathrm{d \omega}}{\mathrm{d\varphi}} = -\frac{g}{R}\,\dfrac{\sin(\varphi)}{\omega}$. I took that to make it $V = [1, -\frac{g}{R}\,\dfrac{\sin(\varphi)}{\omega}]$ because I've been taught the direction field of a first order ODE $y'(x) = f(x,y)$ can be given by $V = [1, f(x,y)]$

However the plots are not matching:

[image] [image]

Why is that? The last one seems not right.

Comment: Note that in the second case you force the first component of $V$ to be positive. That means that you never have a negative $x$ component (your arrows are always pointing to the right). If you replace $1$ with $\textrm{sgn}(\omega)$ you get the right answer. This is similar to going from $\sin$ and $\cos$ to $\tan$. $(-\sin, -\cos)$ and $(\sin,\cos)$ have the same tangent, but they are in opposite quadrants.

Comment: Your reasonings seem logical, but plotting $\left(\begin{array}{c} \text{sgn}(\omega)\\ \dfrac{\sin(\varphi)}{\omega}\end{array}\right)$ gives a weird graph, albeit it should be right.